osdisk.name not allowed in azure bicep
I have recently deployed windows VM using azure bicep. Today i have updated some NSG rules. tried to run .bicep file its shows below error.
{"code":"Deployment Failed","details":[{"code":"PropertyChangeNotAllowed","target":"osDisk.name","message":"Changing property 'osDisk.name' is not allowed."}]}
Note : iam using VM module
How to fix this issue in azure bicep

Make sure that the properties of the existing VM, especially the osDisk.name, remain the same during subsequent deployments & If you are only updating the NSG rules, you might want to decouple the NSG from the VM module to avoid unnecessary changes to the VM itself. @satish B

can you please share the code you tried tried @satishB

Have you made any changes on osDisk.name ? This property is not allowed to change on deployed resource. Some properties can't be modified on existing resources and re-deploy, but some can. you can refer the docs here to find PropertyChangeNotAllowed error explanation.

iam not made any changes on os disk .

that's strange, can you show your sample code? remember to hide your sensitive information

osDisk: {
createOption:'Attach'
caching:'None'
diskSizeGB: 128
managedDisk: {
storageAccountType: 'Premium_LRS'
}
}

where is your whole code ? and why you set createOption with 'Attach', it requires managed disk os existing.

osDisk: {
name:'Nameof os disk'
createOption:'FromImage'
deleteOption: 'Delete'
caching:'ReadWrite'
diskSizeGB: 128
managedDisk: {
id: resourceId('Microsoft.Compute/disks', 'Nameof os disk')
storageAccountType: 'Premium_LRS'
}
}
